# Android: Выполнить функцию, когда тел. звонок закончен

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. В моём приложении, при нажатии на кнопку, вызывается исходящий звонок. Как создать функцию, которая будет по окончанию звонка выводить сообщение `AlertDialog`? То есть нужно создать определитель, который будет определять, когда один из собеседников положил трубку. Я визуально себе представляю это так:

```
// Устанавливаем соединение
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel: 8**********");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri));
// Создаём определитель
onCallClosed {
  AlertDialog...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нагуглил, [статья по теме](http://mobisys.in/blog/2011/09/is-your-call-ended-on-android-phone/)

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">  
</uses-permission>
```

---

```
public class CallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // Phone number 
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            // Ringing state
            // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

            // Тут должно сработать
        }
    }
}
```